# Inno Setup - Is there a way to run an external app from original user during uninstall time?

Tags: powershell, inno-setup, uninstallation, account

In the Inno Setup script I'm currently writing, I need to run a PowerShell command to restore a previously installed Windows extension, while the uninstaller is executed. This command need to run on the original user side, because otherwise the extension will be installed on the wrong account (the admin one, as the uninstaller is run as admin).

During the installation, I can use the `ExecAsOriginalUser()` function to achieve a such task. Unfortunately this function is not allowed at the uninstall time (see https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser remarks)

The PowerShell command I need to execute is the following:

```
winget install -e -h --id=9PMMSR1CGPWG --source=msstore --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --disable-interactivity
```

And here is the code I want ideally to run on uninstall time (but not working, as said above):

```
Result := ExecAsOriginalUser('powershell.exe', 'winget install -e -h --id=9PMMSR1CGPWG --source=msstore --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --disable-interactivity', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

However, as I cannot use `ExecAsOriginalUser()` on uninstall time, what is the correct way to execute a such command in these conditions?

Comment: The application can be uninstalled by a different user than the one that installed it. This cannot work reliably. If the installer is running with Administrator privileges to install the application for all users, it should not do customizations for one specific user, just because that happens to be the user that installed it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl so the only way to resolve the issue would be to execute the command as administrator, and apply it for all users?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the command, so I cannot tell that works.